# Rewriting url using routes in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am trying to create a custom route in cakephp.I need the url in the following format

```
http://domain.com/mygroup?id=23
```

I am trying like the following

```
 Router::connect('/:sluggroup?id=:id', 
 array('controller' => 'groups', 
 'action' => 'postdetail'),array('pass' =>  array('sluggroup','id')));
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks...

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use a URL like: `http://domain.com/mygroup/23` ?

Comment: No specific reason, but is is the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try using the route:

```
Router::connect('/:group/*', array('controller'=>'groups','action'=>'postdetail'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('group')
    )
);
```

This will route everything, so if you have other controllers, you will need specific routes for them BEFORE the one above.

In your Controller's  use:

```
public function postdetails() {
     $group = $this->passedArgs[0];
     $id = $this->request->query('id');
     ...
}
```