# cakephp routing conflicts between two urls

Tags: cakephp-2.3

Iam rewriting the url using cakephp routing.

I have the following roues, it's creating conflicts

```
 Router::connect('/:sluggroup/:postid', 
 array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' =>   'postdetail'),
 array('pass' =>array('sluggroup','postid')));

 Router::connect('/:sluggroup/add', 
 array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'add'),array(
 'pass' => array('sluggroup')));
```

Here the second route is not working, it is going to the first one

How can i solve this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953163/rewriting-url-using-routes-in-cakephp), the first route "grabs" everything.

Move the second route BEFORE the first one:

```
Router::connect('/:group/add', array('controller'=>'groups','action'=>'add'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('group')
    )
);
Router::connect('/:group/*', array('controller'=>'groups','action'=>'postdetail'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('group')
    )
);
```

Comment: if i move the second before first, the the first one will not work